# Installing PHP with an external PCRE library

Tags: linux, php, configuration, installation

**UPDATE**

I keep getting a warning when I use some php regex functions that says "this version of PCRE is not compiled with PCRE_UTF8 support."  I have been digging pretty deep and think that all I need to do is install PCRE from source while the option --enable-utf8 when configuring PCRE.  No problem.  But then I need to tell PHP to find this new PCRE library.  I think I have to install PHP from source and specify an external PCRE library as stated here:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/pcre.installation.php

I think specifying the external PCRE library will involve just adding an option when when i do ./configure

If there is a way to do this while using aptitude?  I need to set options when aptitude does the ./configure.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This seems slightly unusual as I would assume php would come with a Unicode version of the library. What distribution / version of PHP are you using?

You can always get the source package for php (apt-get source php5) and the build dependencies (apt build-dep php5) and then just configure and install as you've mentioned above.

Comment: i agree this is strange.  i am using PHP 5.2.4-2ubuntu5.6.  the thing i am not understanding is that EVERYONE using wordpress2.8 on ubuntu should be experiencing this issue and there is no easy solution.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use PHP higher than 5.2.4. They have [fixed this bug in 5.2.5](http://lt.php.net/ChangeLog-5.php#5.2.5). It says:

> Upgraded PCRE to version 7.3 (Nuno)